# Efficiently imposing structure on data using variadic templates (or other solutions)

Tags: c++, c++11

In my project I am dealing with a lot of 3d maths (so square matrices and vectors up to lengths 4) using floats. Naturally I have made classes to help me and as I have used an array as the datatype for members I know they will be allocated continuously. There are no virtuals so no v-table pointer, so no RTTI, I do have an assert that'll warn me though.

Right now I have something like: (this is pseudo-code, showing what works, but no specifics, for brevity)

```
class program {
    /*...*/
protected:
    Vec4 point_pos;
protected:
    program() {
        register_var("pos",point_pos);
    }
    void prepare() {}
    void run() {
        point_pos.fill(0);
    }
};
class specific_program: public program {
private:
    Mat4x4 mvp;
    Vec3 amb_dir;
    Vec4 vertex;
    Vec4as3<1> surface_norm;
    /*
    Vec4as3 may be assigned to by vec3s, takes the space of vec3;
    but the 4th value is the template param
    */
    Mat4x4 norm_trans;
public:
    specific_program() {
        register_var("a",mvp);
        register_var("b",amb_dir);
        register_var("c",surface_norm);
        register_Var("d",vertex);
    }   

    void prepare() {
        norm_trans = Mat4::inverse(mvp).transpose();
    }

    void run() {
        point_pos = mvp * vertex;
    }
};
```

`register_var` takes a reference and will find the address based on that, it then tells the system "heres where you put this data" and it copies across the required number of floats. Runs it then studies the result. What I would like to do is use the results of the program (such as `point_pos` and any others that are declared as outputs) but not as separate chunks, I'd like instead to have a array of floats and project the structure onto them, for example: (suppose we have outputs point_pos and point_colour)

```
float 0: point_pos.x
float 1: point_pos.y
float 2: point_pos.z
float 3: point_pos.w
float 4: point_colour.x
float 5: point_colour.y
float 6: point_colour.z
/*any floats left (if fixed size) unused*/
```

It'd be much faster if I could deal in buffers of floats. (in the above, 7 floats, rather than 2 variables which *may* not be continuous in memory).

Now in C++11 you have much more powerful meta-programming than before, using the same logic as a tuple, I would like a class which I could use like so:

```
data_buffer<Mat4x4,Vec4,Vec3> variables;
```

Say. Then (worst case) access: `variables.get<0>()*variables.get<1>()`.

It is not quite a tuple though! The compiler **must not** pad these, it must impose structure on an array of floats. For example `start_of_floats+4` is the start of the colour vector in the example above. It could return this cast to a `Vec3&`.

The "lower" (further away from the code structure) optimisations will ensure such a solution is efficient (at least with GCC) so performance wise this'd be fine.

I'm not sure how to do this with templates, the offset to that buffer pointer will come from the template parameters, but I'm not sure how to get the sum of the sizeofs of Ts up to a point into the template.

### Bonus points

Anything you could add, change or do to make this nicer. I want to use objects, this was a practice/experiment, in the past I have used a whole lot of macros and no objects (in C) to do this. I would love a nicer looking way, without the performance penalty.

Comment: So you want prettier views into a raw buffer of `float`s?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I'd start with a design something like this:

```
template<typename ElType, std::size_t N>
class SubArray
{
public:
    typedef ElType value_type;
    typedef ElType* iterator;
    typedef const ElType* const_iterator;
    typedef ElType& reference;
    typedef const ElType& const_reference;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ElType*>::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename std::iteartor_traits<ElType*>::difference_type difference_type;

    explicit SubArray(ElType* ptr);

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
    static constexpr size_type size() const;

    reference operator[](size_type i);
    const_reference operator[](size_type i) const;

private:
    ElType* m_start;
};

template<typename T> class ArrayUserWithStorage;

template<typename ElType, std::size_t N>
class ArrayUser
{
protected:
    typedef ElType element_type;
    static constexpr std::size_t elements();

    explicit ArrayUser(SubArray<ElType, N>);

    SubArray<ElType, N>& storage();
    const SubArray<ElType, N>& storage() const;

private:
    SubArray<ElType, N> m_storage;

    template <typename T>
    friend class ArrayUserWithStorage<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct ArrayUserWithStorage :
    private std::array<typename T::element_type, T::elements()>,
    public ArrayUser<typename T::element_type, T::elements()>
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    ArrayUserWithStorage(Args&& ... args) :
        std::array(),
        T(ArrayUser<typename T::element_type, T::elements()>(data()),
          std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
};

class Vec3 : public ArrayUser<float, 3>
{
public:
    explicit Vec3(SubArray<float, 3> storg);
    Vec3(SubArray<float, 3> storg, float x, float y, float z) :
        ArrayUser(storg)
    {
        storage()[0] = x;
        storage()[1] = y;
        storage()[2] = z;
    }

    // ...
};

typedef ArrayUserWithStorage<Vec3> LoneVec3;

template <typename ElType, typename... Ts>
class ArrayAsTuple
{
    template <std::size_t NToAdd, typename... Us>
    struct offset_helper

    template <std::size_t Sum, typename... Us>
    struct offset_helper<0, Us...>
    {
        static constexpr std::size_t offset = 0;
    };

    template <std::size_t NToAdd, typename U1, typename... Us>
    struct offset_helper<NToAdd, U1, Us...>
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<typename U1::element_type, ElType>::value,
                      "Mismatch in ArrayUser element types");
        static constexpr std::size_t offset =
            U1::elements() + offset_helper<NToAdd-1, Us...>::offset;
    };

    static constexpr total_elements = offset_helper<sizeof...(Ts), Ts...>::offset;

    template <std::size_t I, typename... Us>
    struct nth_type;

    template <typename U1, typename... Us>
    struct nth_type<0, U1, Us...>
    { typedef U1 type; };

    template <std::size_t I, typename U1, typename... Us>
    struct nth_type<I, U1, Us...>
    { typedef typename nth_type<I-1, Us...>::type type; };

    std::array<ElType, total_elements> m_storage;

public:
    using array_type = std::array<ElType, total_elements>;

    ArrayAsTuple();

    array_type& arr() &;
    const array_type& arr() const &;

    template<std::size_t N>
    nth_type<N, Ts...> get() &;
    { return nth_type<N, Ts...>( m_storage.data() + offset_helper<N, Ts...>::offset ); }
};
```